# Структура данных x-tree

Tags: структуры-данных, pascal, delphi

Здравствуйте. Хотел бы попросить помочь разобраться с такой структурой данных как x-tree. Необходимо какой либо материал(желательно на русском) где было бы хорошее описание этой структуры. Будет очень хорошо если будут какие-либо алгоритмы по этой теме. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 2):

В английской википедии [написано](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-tree) что это некая продвинутая версия R-tree, так что не помешает изучить информацию по [R-tree](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)

Отличия этих структур описаны только на английском, судя по всему, но зная R-tree разобраться будет уже не так сложно